# Building Android hybrid mobile application from iOS hybrid mobile application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

We have an iOS mobile application which is built up using native tabbar design, where one tab consist a web view to display Cordova view. The other two tabs are purely native.

Now we are planning to build same application for Android mobiles.

Please guide us how and where to start for migration.

- Do we require to update cordova code for supporting Android or the same code will work?
- How to support various number of Android screen sizes?

Comment: Where to start... with what? Where to start learning Java? Please explain **completely and precisely** where you need assistance.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks for pointing out. Please find updates.

Comment: 1) No need to update the cordova code but you have to create native code for android also for other tab. 2)for web view you can use Bootstrap or Responsive design framework to support multiple screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as answer for future readers.

- No need to update the cordova code but have to create native code for andorid also for other tab
- For web view have to use Bootstrap of Responsive design framworks to support mutilple screes sizes